# Filter events globally in KONVAJS

Tags: events, konvajs

Is it possible (e.g. by overwriting a prototype) to filter (enable/disable) events globally in KONVA?

use case:
I have an interactive app built with KONVA. At the beginning, I want to show a "demonstration" of the user interface: I'm displaying a moving second mouse cursor and fire events which are handled by the app to demonstrate possible interactions. All is working, but during the demonstration, the app should not listen to real mouse events, only to the simulated ones (having a special property set in event object).

Comment: If your mouse events are targeted to shapes then you can stick a massive transparent rect with listening = false  over the entire stage whilst the demo runs. That will allow your demo-events to be fired and stop the user interferring.

Answer (score 0):

For that use case, just set `listening: false` for your stage. It will disable ALL events on the stage and its children.

You can turn off events just for demonstration. As soon as it is done, you can turn mouse/touch/pointers events on with `listening: true`.

Comment: Thank for answering, but you misunderstood me. During the "demo" I'm firing the mouse events (mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, touchstart etc.) using fire(). These events are handled by the app and so the "demo" is showing all user inertactions. That's why also during the demo all handlers have to work, so setting "listening: false" ist no solution. During "demo" the handlers should only react to my fired events (special property in event object is set), not to real user events. That's why I want to "filter"...

Comment: If you set `listening: false`, your custom events triggered by "fire" should work just fine. Did you try that?